# Why ClickOnce c# windows application not updating automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

We Have a C# windows application which can be installed on client computer's and the application runs continuously. So, we want to update application it self if a newer version is available.

If I install the application, implemented below code for update checking, publish it again. When the update available, The application instance close while running but not start automatically. If I click on desktop shortcut again to open the application then the form opened with updated changes.

We want to update the application automatically instead of user interaction.

```
 try
 {
     if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
     {
         ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
         UpdateCheckInfo info;
         try
         {
             info = ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate();
         }
         catch (DeploymentDownloadException dde)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("The new version of the application cannot be downloaded at this time. \n\nPlease check your network connection, or try again later. Error: " + dde.Message);
             return;
         }
         catch (InvalidDeploymentException ide)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Cannot check for a new version of the application. The ClickOnce deployment is corrupt. Please redeploy the application and try again. Error: " + ide.Message);
             return;
         }
         catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("This application cannot be updated. It is likely not a ClickOnce application. Error: " + ioe.Message);
             return;
         }
         if (info.UpdateAvailable)
         {
             try
             {
                  ad.Update();
                  Application.Restart();

             }
             catch (DeploymentDownloadException dde)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the latest version of the application. \n\nPlease check your network connection, or try again later. Error: " + dde);
                 return;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             //MainForm.Logg.Info("No update available");
         }
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.InnerException?.Message + " in AutoUpdate Timer");
 }
```

In place of `Application.Restart();`, tried another ways like
`Application.Exit(); Process.Start(processname);` but still getting same issue.

As per clickonce documents, tied to change settings in updates section of publish tab. Tried to set minimum version but no result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If ClickOnce doesn't work in your particular development environment, you can update your application in addition to ClickOnce by using HttpWebRequest.

This method allows developers to better control the updated logic and process, but it requires writing a lot of code. The implementation steps are as follows:

1. Write an update check program to initiate a request to the server and obtain the current version and latest version information;
2. If you find that an update is needed, download the latest version of the software;
3. When the download is completed, open the downloaded software and implement software update.

Here's a simple example:

```
//Initiate a request to the server to obtain version information
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

//Read the version information returned by the server
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string versionStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
Version serverVersion = new Version(versionStr);

//Check for version updates
if (serverVersion > currentVersion)
{
     //Download update file
     WebClient client = new WebClient();
     client.DownloadFile(updateUrl, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "update.exe"));

     //Start the updater and close the application
     Process.Start(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "update.exe"), "restart");
     Application.Exit();
}
```

**Update:**

Regarding your issue of being unable to update successfully using ClickOnce, you can try using the methods recommended in the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.checkfordetailedupdate?view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: I tried above code, Application open again but not with updated changes. Any alternative to restart app with updated changes using click once?

Comment: Hi, I tried two ways none of this works.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer again

Comment: Regarding your issue of being unable to update successfully using ClickOnce, will it work if you use the code in the following document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.checkfordetailedupdate?view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: Hi, I tried by using the above link. it's working. Thank you:)

Comment: Hi @AnushaReddy, I updated my answer. If it helps you, you can mark it so that it can help more people